# Android Soundpool Load(String path, int priority)

Tags: android, audio, resources, soundpool

I am trying to load a sound from android.
The sound is under `res/raw/myownsound.wav`.
I know that I can already load the sound using:

```
 soundPool.load(context, R.raw.myownsound, 1)
```

For customization purposes, I would like to load it using:

```
 soundPool.load("res/raw/myownsound", 1)
```

... but I get the following error : `error loading res/raw/myownsound`.
I also tried the following :

```
 soundPool.loadSound("android.resource://upg.GraphismeBase/raw/myownsound", 1)
```

.. but I get an error as well : `error loading android.resource://upg.GraphismeBase/raw/myownsound`

What is the correct way of using soundPool.load(path, priority) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple working way of doing so with a context named `mContext`.
It loads the resource by name by getting the identifier id at run-time.

```
int sound_id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("myownsound", "raw",
                                                     mContext.getPackageName());
soundPool.load(mContext, sound_id, 1);
```

It also works to load drawables or xml files, by replacing `"raw"` by `"drawable"` or `"xml"` for example.

Answer (score 6):

Create a folder structure in your project

```
/assets/sounds/data/
```

Then copy your wav file there.

```
// Declare globally if needed
int mySoundId;
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0 );
AssetManager am = this.getAssets();

//Use in whatever method is used to load the sounds
try {
    mySoundId = soundPool.load(am.openFd("sounds/data/myownsound"), 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

May try this (not sure its working) :

```
SoundPool mySoundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    int myAudioFile = getResId("claps", R.raw.class);
    try{
        mySoundPool.load(context.getActivity(),myAudioFile,1);
    } catch (Exception e){
        message = String.valueOf(e);
    }

public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {
    Field field = null;
    int resId = 0;
    try {
        field = c.getField(variableName);
        try {
            resId = field.getInt(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resId;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's surely a working answer, but I would really like to know here how to use the pure path version, not the FileDescriptor one.

Comment: I putted a second method, may this is what you want

Comment: Where do you import the Field class ?

Comment: java.lang.reflect.Field - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html